# get error inside a emit event in socket.io

Tags: socket.io

I want to catch any error in client side inside 'emit' event, not in any default event.The code is below:

Client:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:8082',{
    'force new connection': true
});
socket.emit('messageToServer',{"phoneNo":phoneNo},function (ack) {
     console.log(ack);
     // i want to handle any error here
});
```

Server:

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket) {
    socket.on('messageToServer', function (data,fn) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        fn("Connected To Server");
        setTimeout(function () {
            socket.emit("messageFromServer",data,function (ack) {
                console.log(ack);
            });
        },30*1000);

    });
 })
```

I can get the error in any default socket event but I need it inside the emit event.How it's possible?

Comment: I'm unclear what you are trying to capture or attempt.  Are you trying to send any errors that occur on the server back to the client?  Or errors that might occur on the server due to a client emitting an event? Something else?

Comment: The error that might occur on the server side.Actually, I want to get notified from another side(server) that an error has occurred so that I can handle(store/save) the emitted data.It's a reverse situation(for client and server) also.